# CLI Application Unknown error in Java

Tags: java

I wrote a socket client in java that 24/7 connected to a socket server and receive data from it.
the client is running for about 3 days in testing, everything looks fine, and than suddenly I saw this message in the eclipse console (No stack trace):

> ServerCommunicatorAdmin reqIncoming
>   The server has decided to close this
>   client connection.

I restart the application and now its working again.
I asked the server sysadmin, he says that everything looks fine the his logs.

my system uses mysql jdbc and log4j.

Any idea what can be the source?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Google ServerCommunicatorAdmin you'll see that it's part of JMX

> com.sun.jmx.remote.internal:
>   ServerCommunicatorAdmin.java

and if you search for "reqIncoming The server has decided to close this client connection" you get lots of hits.  There should be something in there to help you.